# IOS 8 WebApp: WebSQL after standby is not responding

Tags: ios, web-applications, fixed, web-sql, pouchdb

I made a WebApp with PouchDB and I noticed some problems every time I go into standby. I know that PouchDB uses WebSQL.
So I made a test, you can see here: https://shdev.github.io/playground/websql.html

What happens there:

- On startup a PouchDB database and a webSQL database will created. (PouchDB uses websql as underlying database)
- on button click it gives out

  - the PouchDB adapters
  - The rows from the websql database
  - the info from the PouchDB database

I started this page on my IOS 8.0.2 devices iPhone 4s and iPad 3. In Safari on these devices are problems the click gives all three lines as output. Go to standby. Resume. Click the button again three lines.

Now add this webpage to the home screen. Start it from the home screen.
Click the button -> three lines. Standby, resume. Click the button -> one line.
The WebSql seems not to respond and execute the transaction functions. I tried also with the developer tools get some information but got nothing.

On my IOS 6.1.6 iPod touch I got three lines after standby.

Has someone else the same problems? How can I avoid it?

**Update:** It's still present with IOS 8.1

**Update:** The Bug is reported to Apple it has the number #18042389

**Update:** With IOS 8.2 it works! Yeah!

Comment: How to develop an ios native app with Punch DB, is there any SDK for ios

Comment: Hi @srinadh I have experience just with web devs.  Take a look at <http://pouchdb.com/faq.html#native_support>.

Comment: Hey thanks man, i got solution, im looking couchbase lite for this